# Make DIV overide margins of parent

Tags: css, html

I'm not sure how best to explain this, but I'll do my best. I have Drupal theme that has a shadow border and text padding on the main content/post DIV. However, on some pages, I would like to override the text padding so that a DIV tag can be full with of the content DIV.

I could probably achieve the same sort of thing by removing the text padding and adding it manually on each page, but this would be a lot of work; especially considering that I would only need to use this *"special"* DIV on a few pages.

I hope that makes some sense - there's probably a better way to explain it though which is why I can not find the answer myself! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative margin on the child that is equal to the parent's padding. I.e:

```
div.parent {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

div.child {
  margin: 0 -10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I wanted. Can't believe I didn't try that :')